# Grails render changes url to index

Tags: url, grails

I've got this method on my controller, which basically validates and saves entity or renders errors if any:

```
def initCreateProduct() {
    render view: "/admin/product/createProduct"
}

def createProduct(params) {
    def product = new Product(params)
    if (product.validate()) {
        flash.message = "product.createSuccess"
        product.save(failOnError: true);
        redirect action: "initCreateProduct"
    } else {
        render view: "/admin/product/createProduct", model: [product: product]
    }
}
```

It works fine in case if validation is successfull (URL in browser is "product/initCreateProduct", which is ok), but in case if validation fails my URL changes to "product/index", which is wrong. What I need is to get the same URL in both cases (it's the same page after all). Thanks in advance.

Update: finally solved it.

The problem is caused by  used in my gsp, which basically changes action url to  index, and sends real action as post-method parameter. To save action in url I have used  instead of

Comment: That doesn't really make sense.  I mean, you're question makes sense, but the grails behavior doesn't.  Do you have an index() method?  Do you have any URL Mappings for these controller actions that could be causing the odd redirect URL?

Comment: No, I don't have index method. My URL Mapping for this controller is ""/admin/product/$action?"(controller: "product")".

Answer (score 0):

It is doing a controller redirect and not being able to resolve an URL. IIRC, grails will pass additional parameters to the index method to find that action.

If you do something like this, it won't do it:

```
if (product.validate()) {
        flash.message = "product.createSuccess"
        product.save(failOnError: true)
        initCreateProduct()
}
```

Comment: I've tried your approach, but it still gives me index in url. (I've used it's like "else { initCreateProduct() }")